# How to install package in alpine in a specific folder using apk package manager?

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to install a package in an Alpine Docker image. I am able to install the package and also able to verify them but now I want to install all the packages in my current working directory, let's say in a bin folder

How can I do this using apk package manager?

or

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Using apk, I don't think you can. But why tho?

Comment: I am using github codespaces now theses days... there is a feature in github codespaces that whenever you spinup your codespace, it will download your dotfiles and scripts from your dotfiles repository..

I just want to use the apk install feature to install my list of package based on the project I am opening. 

and it should display the packages in a  bin file created in the repository. 

I don't want to use the default bin folder of the codespace docker imgage.

Answer (score 0):

this may not work for every package, but you could try fetching and running locally, eg:

> apk fetch PKG-NAME

Then extract the package contents locally:

> tar zxvf PKG-NAME.apk

Then run whatever files are present.

However this only works when the package's installation doesn't depend on it's install location.